# Is the power of a natural number logspace-computable?

Tags: space-complexity, transducers

Given a constant $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$, is the simple power function
$$
λ\,x\in\mathbb{N}_+.\,x^n
$$
logspace computable by a logspace transducer (which has a read-only input tape, a working read-write tape (on which the transducer is allowed to use $\mathcal{O}(\log (\text{input size}))$) cells, and a write-only output tape), assuming that the input and the output are in binary?  (It is not even clear to me how to do it for $n=2$ in logspace.) Any ideas or references?

Comment: How would it work in log space if the size of the output is exponential in the size of the input? I know you specified a transducer but still the computation will take exponential size to reach it. I am not saying it does not work I have no experience in that area but I find it very interesting if it works

Comment: @narekBojikian The size of the input is roughly $\log x$, whereas the size of the output is roughly $\log(x^n) = n\log x$, i.e., linear in the size of the input.

Comment: Assuming n is a constant?

Comment: @narekBojikian Yes. The function to be computed has only $x$ as input, not $n$. I've just made an edit to emphasize this.

Comment: But then the trivial method is already log space isnt it? I mean we never grow above the output and you said the output is small enouph

Comment: @narekBojikian The trivial, "school" method involves additions of intermediate results. You need to store the intermediate results somewhere for this to work. But, on the working tape you don't have linear space in the input size (i.e., $\mathcal{O}(\log x)$). Instead, you have only logarithmic space (i.e., $\mathcal{O}(\log \log x)$). Similary, doing repeated squaring needs to store intermediate results. Of course, there might be some trick unknown to me, but I don't see it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, iterated multiplication is even in [uniform TC<sup>0</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TC0):

Hesse, William; Allender, Eric; Mix Barrington, David (2002). "[Uniform constant-depth threshold circuits for division and iterated multiplication](http://ftp.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/division.pdf)". Journal of Computer and System Sciences. 65: 695–716. doi:[10.1016/S0022-0000(02)00025-9](https://doi.org/10.1016%2FS0022-0000%2802%2900025-9).

Explanation: We have TC<sup>0</sup> ⊆ NC<sup>1</sup> ⊆ L, where TC<sup>0</sup> denotes the class of Boolean circuits with constant depth and polynomial size, where unbounded fan-in threshold gates are allowed, NC<sup>1</sup> denotes the class of Boolean circuits with logarithmic depth and polynomial size, and L denotes logspace.

Comment: First, thanks. Second, is the a direct transducer description (rather a transducer evaluating a circuit), perhaps? Third, does your answer imply a positive solution for https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116253/are-polynomials-in-one-variable-logspace-computable ?

Comment: @MdAyq Since logspace is closed under composition, the well-known [logspace multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Optimizing_space_complexity) variant of long multiplication should give you a more direct transducer description. The same argument (closure under composition) also implies a positive solution for that other question. But the transducer evaluating the composition is also ugly (= inefficient in terms of runtime) in a certain sense.

Comment: But isn't it the case that [logspace multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Optimizing_space_complexity) produces the output starting from the least significant digit, whereas a logspace transducer is expected to output the most significant digit first? This is a non-issue if the logspace Turing machine can output from right to left, but it is an issue if it moves one-way, as usual, from left to right.

Comment: @MdAyq A string can be reversed too by a logspace transducer. An again, because of that ulgy closure under composition, this is enough.

Comment: Yes, this gets ugly. I see that a direct transducer description (without logspace composition steps) is likely to be cumbersome.